# Why am I getting scroll bars in this div?

Tags: css, overflow

http://jsfiddle.net/BCTF9/

I have set the overflow as I want to restrict the height of the boxes and have a scroll show up when needed; so I added `overflow-y: auto;` as that generally does the trick. But now I see horizontal scroll bars on the second box in the example as well, though I'm not sure why?

I tried adding `overflow-x: visible;` but it didn't work. I don't want to set any widths on these boxes as they just need to be the width of the content + some padding.

You will also see the vertical scroll bars start too soon and don't allow the padding needed.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/BCTF9/1/)**

**Two reasons and fixes**

The content in the second div taking too much width causing horizontal overflow, so increase the width

Instead of `overflow-x:visible` try `overflow-x:hidden` to hide horizontal scrollbar even if the width is higher

Comment: That works to get rid of the scroll bar, but still misses the padding on the right side - I noted you added a width, which I don't really want to do as the boxes will vary in size.

Comment: Not an issue, Just remove width and increase padding-right of li. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/BCTF9/2/)

Comment: but won't that result in larger padding than usual on the right when the boxes don't have a scroll bar?

Comment: That we can't do anything with pure CSS, Or you can show Scollbar only on hover like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/BCTF9/3/) or use a jquery Scroll plugin like facebook

Answer (score 0):

The scroll bars are appearing because there are many items in second div.
Try to remove these items, and they'll go away.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Upt7/)

```
.cat_list {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Replace it

Comment: That works to get rid of the scroll bar, but still misses the padding on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

CSS

```
.cat_list{ height:200px;
         background:#e4e4e4; 
         width:200px; 
         overflow:hidden; 
         overflow-y:scroll; 
         overflow-x:hidden;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="cat_list"></div>
```